# Tripple integral of 1 where $0 \le z \le x^2+4y^2 ; x^2+y^2 \le 1$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Problem: $\iiint_K 1 dx dy dz$ where $0 \le z \le x^2+4y^2$ and $x^2+y^2 \le 1$ I need to calculate the volume of this.

Attempt: I suspect that I need **cylinder coordinates** since it's a spehere. Also, I think it can be simplified to $0 \le z \le 1+3y^2$ where I chose the "chose and remove" method for integral boundaries. But here I'm stuck, if you write the solution I think I will understand how to calculate them in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use cylindrical coordinates since $x^2+4y^2$ will not match perfectly, it would be more trouble, I feel. The bounds of the integral are quite obvious already.

$$\int _{-1}^1\int _{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int _0^{x^2+4 y^2}dzdydx$$

First we consider the bounds of $z$, then we parametrize the circle for $y$

The two inner integral are very easy, you get:

$$\int_{-1}^1 \left(\frac{8 \sqrt{1-x^2}}{3}-\frac{2}{3} x^2 \sqrt{1-x^2}\right) \, dx$$

The first term is simply the area of a semicircle. You can substitute $x=\sin t$ to do it algebraically. For the second term, after doing the substitution, you'll have $\sin^2 t \cos^2 t dt$. Use sin double angle formula twice and then use cosine double angel formula. You should get in the end (final result):

$$\frac{5 \pi }{4}$$

Comment: But since I'm asked to, can it be done? Or maybe with spherical coordnaes or some other variable transformation?

Comment: Woudl have been better if you said that it was a part of the assignment. This is the bounds in cylindrical: $$\int _0^{2 \pi }\int _0^1\int _0^{4 r^2 \sin ^2(t)+r^2 \cos ^2(t)}rdzdrdt$$ Turns out you were right, this is indeed quite a bit easier to evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from 
$$\int _{-1}^1\int _{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int _0^{x^2+4 y^2}dz\,dy\,dx
$$
Converting to polar coordinates, we get
$$\begin{align}
&\;\;\;\;\int _{0}^{2\pi}\int _{0}^{1}\int _0^{r^2(1+3\sin^2\theta)}r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta\\
&=\int _{0}^{2\pi}\int _{0}^{1}r^3(1+3\sin^2\theta)\,dr\,d\theta\\
&=\int _{0}^{2\pi}\left(\frac14+\frac34\sin^2\theta\right)\,d\theta\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{4}+\frac34\pi\\
&=\frac{5\pi}{4}
\end{align}
$$